# Min-Heap based priority queue class written in ES6

Tags: javascript, heap, ecmascript-6, priority-queue

I would appreciate any feedback on syntax, naming convention, possible shortcuts, clarity of code and any other constructive feedback. This code was based off of the Priority Queue chapter in *The Algorithm Design Manual*.

## CODE

```
'use strict';

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

class PriorityQueue {
    constructor(values) {
        this._n = -1;
        this._Q = [];

        if (Array.isArray(values)) {
            for (let value of values) {
                this.insert(value);
            }
        }
    }

    get n() {
        return this._n;
    }

    set n(value) {
        this._n = value;
        return;
    }

    get Q() {
        return this._Q;
    }

    set Q(value) {
        this._Q = value;
        return;
    }

    getParent(n) {
        if (n === 0) return -1;
        return Math.floor((n - 1) / 2);
    }

    getYoungChild(n) {
        return (n + 1) * 2 - 1;
    }

    insert(x) {
        this.Q[++this.n] = x;
        this.bubbleUp(this.n);
    }

    bubbleUp(x) {
        var parent = this.getParent(x);
        if (this.Q[parent] > this.Q[x]) {
            this.swap(parent, x);
            this.bubbleUp(parent);
        }
    }

    bubbleDown(parent) {
        var child = this.getYoungChild(parent);
        var min_index = parent;

        for (let i=0; i<=1; i++) {
            if (this.Q[min_index] > this.Q[child+i]) min_index = child+i;
        }

        if (min_index !== parent) { 
            this.swap(parent, min_index);
            this.bubbleDown(min_index);
        }
    }

    swap(x, y) {
        var temp = this.Q[x];
        this.Q[x] = this.Q[y];
        this.Q[y] = temp;
    }

    extractMin() {
        if (this.n < 1) throw 'The queue is empty.';

        var min = this.Q[0];

        if (this.n === 1) {
            this.Q = [];
            this.n = 0;
            return min;
        }

        if (this.n === 2) {
            this.Q = [this.Q[1]];
            this.n = 1;
            return min;
        }

        this.Q[0] = this.Q.splice(this.n, 1)[0];
        this.bubbleDown(0);
        this.n--;

        return min;
    }

    heapsort() {
        var original = this.Q;
        var A = [];

        for (let i=0; i<=this.n; i++) {
            A.push(this.extractMin());
        }
        this.Q = original;
        return A;
    }
}

var test = [];
for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
    test.push(getRandomInt(0, 999));
}

console.log('test array is', test);

var pq = new PriorityQueue(test);

console.log(pq.heapsort());
```